# How to setup postgres with Kubernetes using Deis Workflow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, deis

I am using `Google container engine` and `Deis Workflow` to run my rails application. I do not have a dockerfile, I just use Heroku buildpack.I was successfully able to deploy my app but I am not able to configure my database. I understand that my database cannot reside in my application, it has to be another service which will persist data. I am thinking of using AWS RDB and I think I will want to configure something like what is pointed [here on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds).

I am new to Kubernetes and this workflow, I would really appriciate if someone can point me out how to proceed and achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Helm Charts repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts). 
After [installing Helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/README.md#install) you can run:

```
helm install stable/postgresql
```